# why is npm not creating the project?

Tags: npm, html-framework-7

I'm trying to create a project using npm on ubuntu 20 but getting this error

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-HP-Laptop-14-ck0xxx:~/Projects/hybrid/pdf$ framework7 create
✔ All good, you have latest framework7-cli version.
? What type of the app are you targeting? Cordova app (targets native iOS and Android apps, or native desktop app with Electron)
? App (project) name: pdf
? App package (Bundle ID): s
? Target Cordova platform: iOS, Android
? What type of framework do you prefer? Framework7 Core
? Choose starter template: Blank
? Should we setup project with bundler? Webpack (recommended)
? Do you want to setup CSS Pre-Processor No, i am good with CSS
? Do you want to specify custom theme color? No, use default color theme
? Do you want to include Framework7 Icons and Material Icons icon fonts? Yes, include icon fonts
✔ Generating package.json
✔ Creating required folders structure
✖ Error installing NPM Dependencies
```

I ensured that I'm connected to stable internet and still I can't create the app. Is it happening due to ubuntu. I tried the same command on windows and it works.

Comment: Which version of `node` and `npm` are you using ?

Comment: I solved this issue by uninstalling node(which is installed from apt) and download it from nvm. Strange enough, apt is downloading version 10 of node which I feel is main reason for error. @Reqven